# cant use a Dictionary in setAttributes() of UIText.textStorage

Tags: dictionary, swift2

in Swift1 i could call this:

```
func selectParagraphAlignment(newAlignment:NSTextAlignment) {
    var selectedRange = textView.selectedRange
    var newParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    newParagraphStyle.alignment = newAlignment

    var dict = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: newParagraphStyle]
    textView.textStorage.beginEditing()
    textView.textStorage.setAttributes(dict, range: selectedRange)
    textView.textStorage.endEditing()
}
```

In Swift2 i cant use a Distionary in  textView.textStorage.setAttributes(). I cant see, what i must use now?

Can u show me the new syntax?
TIA

Comment: It works. It's just that now textView.textStorage is an Optional, otherwise it's still the same, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Eric: ok, got the solution in this case. ;-) But i´ve trouble here for that i must ask another question :-(